# X509 Certificate with Subject UID

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, cryptography, x509certificate

I am loading a certificate from string like this:

```
public static void Test()
{
    byte[] arrayCertificate;
    arrayCertificate = Convert.FromBase64String("CERT_STRING");
    X509Certificate2 clientCertificateFromXml = new X509Certificate2(arrayCertificate);
    Console.Write(clientCertificateFromXml);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

But this certificate doesn't have a "Subject Unique Identifier"
Take a look at this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509 (The part of **Structure of a certificate**)

And I want to know how can I read that value from my .NET code (I looked that I can get SerialNumber, Thumbprints and others but there is no Subject UID anywhere).

Also, I will really appreciate If anyone can share an openssl command to include this UID for the certificate :-) (pfx one)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And I want to know how can I read that value from my .NET code

IIRC this is not exposed in the .NET BCL, either from `X509Certificate` or the newer (better but still incomplete) `X509Certificate2`.

But you can use [Mono.Security](https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/Mono.Security) assembly (or just the code you want from it), from the [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) project. It's open source, MIT.X11 licensed and it includes it's own `X509Certificate`.

This version expose just about everything in X.509 certificates, including a [SubjectUniqueIdentifier](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.X509/X509Certificate.cs#L495) property.

> I will really appreciate If anyone can share an openssl command to include this UID for the certificate

I do not recall for openssl... but you can use the `X509CertificateBuilder` from Mono.Security to create your own certificates. See Mono's `makecert` tool source code for an example.

**Disclaimer**: I wrote the code :-)

Comment: Thanks for replying, i will test the mono.security assembly and I will let you know :-)