# X500DistinguishedName with UID field

Tags: c#, security, x509certificate2

I am using X509Certificate2 from C# System.Security.Cryptography that is signed by my certificate authority coming from a certificate request. This certificate request is built using an X500DistinguishedName that should have both CN (commonName) and UID (userId).

However, when I try to create an X500DistinguishedName with distinguished name string as "UID=123,CN=name" I get an error "The string contains an invalid X500 name, attribute key, OID, value or delimiter". But I guess that the problem is UID field as when using distinguished name string as "O=123,CN=name" it works.

I found and old question that mentioned that was not possible at the time ( [X509 Certificate with Subject UID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999379/x509-certificate-with-subject-uid)), but maybe it is already possible now.

Does anyone know how can I set distinguished name with UID field in c#?

Thanks,
Davide Costa

Comment: What is your goal? What is the point to use obsolete UID?

Comment: I am using the certificate for RabbitMQ TLS. RabbitMQ checks for the CN to check connection came from that IP address and so I need the CN with that value. In my case, a multi-agent system, I also need that certificate has some identification regarding the agent using it (his id) and I find UID to be the more suitable field for it. Do you suggest another one?

Comment: I believe you misunderstand your application documentation/requirements. `Subject UID` is certainly not what you are looking for. Maybe, your application expects specific RDN in subject field or specific value in Subject Alternative Names extension? We can't tell that without documentation.

Comment: The requirements are just that certificate has agent Id in the most appropriate field and that the field being used is part of DN (I need that when executing "openssl x509 -in cert.pem -nameopt RFC2253 -subject -noout" field is printed)
Documentation can be found at https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-auth-mechanism-ssl/blob/master/README.md. They have two possibilities, DN or CN, but I cannot use CN for agent id as it is being used for ip address

Answer (score 3):

UID can be specified using its OID ([0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4519#section-2.39)):

```
var subject = new X500DistinguishedName("CN=123,OID.0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1=321");
```

It produces correct ASN.1 structure with user identifier inside. To verify it you can get `subject.RawData`, convert to base64 and paste to any ASN.1 viewer.

RDN attribute has its own object identifier (OID) and value. Note that name aliases like CN, UID, etc are not stored in the resulting ASN.1. So it's up to implementation how to represent (or print) different OIDs.

.NET Framework's implementation of `X500DistinguishedName` performs calls to crypt32.dll to encode/decode the distinguished name, however the crypt32.dll has no idea about not-so-popular name aliases like UID.

It's worth to note that some CAs might not support UID as well, so they might enroll certificate w/o UID attribute even if it was in the CSR originally.